# How to calculate max CPU / Mem usage with Datadog API (Python)

Tags: datadog

I am trying to query the datadog server for some specific metrics ie. "max mem used" over some period x and I'm doing the following:

```
time_period = 7200
end = int(time()) # time period in secodns over which data will be fetched
start = end - time_period

query = "max:system.mem.used{host:<hostname>}" 

results = api.Metric.query(start=start - time_period, end=end, query=query)
```

I would have expect a single timestamped value to be returned, however I get datapoint for every minute like so:
`[
          1581084600000,
          1339840512
        ],
        [
          1581084660000,
          1339883520
        ],
        [
          1581084720000,
          1339740160
        ]`

Is there a way to get a specific result, i.e. the maximum out of all these results?

Thanks.